# Is MVC easy for a Classic ASP guy to learn

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp-classic

I've pretty much worked with Classic ASP for ever since it was released almost.. But i am having trouble adapting to the ASP.NET platform.

I have been suggested by many to move to PHP, since it's spaghetti code (I LIKE SPAGHETTI CODE), and it's just like classic asp.. But learning Apache servers and securing them i heard was another big project to learn by yourself.. And since i know more about MS servers, i prefer to stay with MS.

But, I really want to learn another platform, and i was looking at MVC framework and that MVC 1, 2 or 3 is like spaghetti code? Maybe i'm wrong. I assume MVC3 is the best now?

Anyway, From Classic ASP, which would be the easiest and most difficult to grasp you think?  ASP.NET with all the compiling and using visual studio, reminds me of when i used to make apps in Visual Basic, but i really like spaghetti code more than compiling stuff..

If there is anyone who has done this switch over from classic asp before, what did you do and why, how easy was it to grasp the new platform? (Preferrably MVC)

Answer (score 7):

Well, MVC is more like classic asp than webforms is.  However, it uses structure and frameworks to reduce spaghetti code and make it more maintainable.  You have to apply a lot of new concepts to not fight the framework.

For example, a strong seperation of view, model, and controller.  This is not something you would do in classic asp, or even generic php (you can do mvc in php, but it requires more discipline and using frameworks as well).

Bottom line is, spaghetti will always bite you in the long run.

Asp.net supports a mode where you don't have to compile anything, you just edit the files on the server and it compiles them at runtime automatically.  This is the so called "Web site" model.  However, MVC does not work that way and requires the "Web application" model that does compiling (although you only have to compile code, not markup).

Comment: I just always seem to have a problem using special html tags to work with the server code, is this how all the MVC's are ?

Comment: @Jeremy - MVC does not use special html tags, well not in the same way as Webforms.. html5 is very special attribute heavy, and this has nothing to do with server side.  MVC uses code nuggets (like classic asp) to insert values which render out to regular html.

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently smack in the middle of my first large ASP.NET MVC project after (and while still) programming in classic ASP for years. I have also programmed in ColdFusion and I have tried Python as an alternative to ASP.NET MVC.

If you want to stick to Microsoft technology MVC is the closest you will come to classic ASP. Webforms is really Microsofts way to make web-applications similar to application development. Microsoft has tried to abstract away the fact that the web is a stateless medium. However, this results in pretty ugly things such as the viewstate (a hidden form field that tries to keep the state of all form fields) and controls that generate HTML over which you have absolutely no control.
MVC gives you more control, and leaves you to handle the statelessness like classic ASP does.

I have still found there is a steep learning curve though; you will have to learn a lot of new things, if all you ever did was program vbscript/ASP:

- C# or VB.Net Syntax
- Object oriented programming in general (inheritance, dynamic versus static, etc.)
- Concepts such as lambda expressions, delegates etc.
- The MVC pattern
- Most likely also a data-access technology like LINQ or Entity Framework

I'm still struggling with some of these, but I'm getting there. It does take a lot of work though, and perseverance. Not everything is better or easier than in classic ASP. Especially for me, as I have been using WSC's in classic ASP for years, which enables n-tier applications in classic ASP, and eliminates spaghetti code completely.

As I mentioned, I also looked into Python as an alternative; Although at the company I work for we now switched to ASP.NET MVC, I actually found the transition to Python a lot easier. The only reason we went with MVC is the fact that it seemed easier to get new developers when using C#/MVC. (In retrospect this wasn't actually true, we are having an incredible hard time finding a suitable C# programmer around where we are located)

Mind you, in Python you will still have to learn basic Object Oriented programming, but the implementation is much simpler to use than .NETs and the Python language is (IMHO) more like vbscript than VB.NET is.
Also I liked the fact that I don't have to define the type of every variable/function/parameter. This sometimes drives me crazy in C#; if the type of a function changes, it could affect a lot of other functions and variables, which all have to be changed. Also, the syntax is easier to pick up because the language is simple and there aren't a hundred ways to do the same thing.
You can choose between different frameworks, MVC or non-MVC and you can use Python in a lot of other fields as well (application programming, scripting-for example XBMC).
There are also ORM solutions available like Entity Framework for .NET and I found the one I looked into (SQLalchemy) a lot more powerful, and easier to pick up than EF.

So at work I'm currently learning ASP.NET MVC, at home I'm slowly picking up Python. I suggest you try a very simple project in different technologies, and pick the one you find easiest to get started with.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you like your spaghetti served by Microsoft, try any Windows version that supports IIS7. PHP works perfectly and it's really easy to setup with [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx).

With that in mind, there is no real reason you should choose any one web technology over the other. You can mix and match as needed, even within a single app.

If you want to get into MVC, forget about 1 and 2 and go straight to 3. MVC is much closer to the metal than ASP.NET WebForms. With your background in classic ASP, you'll probably like it once you get the hang of it.

**Update:**
If you're serious about learning either MVC, PHP, Ruby or whatever web platform you like. Get a good book. Sit down, read it and follow along with the sample code. I usually decide what book to buy based on the reviews at amazon.
Then, if you need more info on specific topics, go read authorative blogs on the subject. For ASP.NET MVC you'll probably want to look at blogs from [Brad Wilsons](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/aspnet_mvc/) and [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/tags/aspnetmvc/default.aspx).

Comment: I was thinking about IIS and PHP, but i just have mixed feelings about this.. I figure PHP is best on Apache, right?

You're saying MVC3 is the closest to classic asp?

Comment: @Jeremy - Why would PHP be best on apache?  There's nothign Apache specific about it.  It's server agnostic.  In fact, IIS has special "fast" interfaces for systems like perl and php.

Comment: I looked at PHP and theres way too many configurations.. It would take me forever to learn all that!

Comment: 9 times out of 10, you don't need to bother with configuration files. I'm a .NET developer mostly, but I deployed a PHP site a couple of days ago without ever touching any configuration files. Try [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) (free) and see what you think. It'll do both MVC and PHP. You can install any framework or CMS you like and get started.

Answer (score 1):

I started using Classic ASP back in the days but then moved to WebForms now using/learning MVC 4.

Here are my thoughts.

For me Classic ASP was fun and easy to learn as it was simple and did not have a large learning curve, data CRUDS were not difficult either and it did the job in a fairly efficient but messy manner.

WebForms required a higher learning curve but helped with a lot of 'plumbing' code with drag and drop controls, however these were sometimes difficult to modify and customise.

With MVC I have found it requires a larger learning curve than the other two, this is mainly due to it being driven by HTML5 and client frameworks like Knockout etc. To gain a good understanding also requires one to learn OO patterns, Entity Framework, LINQ, WebApi and initially these I did not find simple to digest.

Answer (score 0):

What is easy for you? What part do you find difficult? Read up about a stateless nature of HTTP and find comparisons between web forms and MVC - this should make few things clear.

Do some reading about MVC pattern in general. MVC is a general term which appeared first time over 30 years ago. MVC in .NET 4 is a variation of this pattern, but we are all used to calling it MVC. Make sure you OO knowledge is up to scratch, as well as knowledge of basic design patterns, mainly SoC (Seperation of Concerns) and SRP (Single Responsibility Principle).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to learn / start with the mvc framework I could recommend you do the Contoso University tutorial or the NerdDinner one ( http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials#NerdDinner )